# JavaFX: Showing a dialog in browser on fullscreen mode

Tags: javafx-2, modal-dialog, fullscreen

I'm experiencing some weird behavior while trying to show a dialog on my application when my Stage is on fullscreen mode.

Everything works OK while I'm launching my application as a standalone app. When I run from the browser, the modal dialog takes the Stage out of fullscreen. Although, it doesn't go really "out" of fullscreen mode... The code still thinks it's fullscreen (fullscreenProperty == true), but it doesn't show as fullscreen. And after closing the dialog, if you press <kbd>ESC</kbd> (which would take you out of fullscreen mode), the application crashes.

Here's a sample code:

```
public class Test1 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage primaryStage) {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                Stage dialogStage = new Stage(StageStyle.UTILITY);
                dialogStage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
                dialogStage.setScene(new Scene(VBoxBuilder.create().
                    children(new Text("Hi"), new Button("Ok.")).
                    alignment(Pos.CENTER).padding(new Insets(5)).build()));
                dialogStage.initOwner(primaryStage);
                dialogStage.show();
                System.out.println(primaryStage.isFullScreen());
            }
        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);

        Rectangle2D r = Screen.getPrimary().getBounds();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, r.getWidth(), r.getHeight());

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
```

Any idea how to solve this? Or any idea of what I can use instead of a Stage dialog?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I also experienced these kind of issues with using JavaFX 2.2 and 8 early access b94 in full screen mode on OSX 10.8 and came up with no solution or workaround (other than to avoid dialogs, which isn't really a workaround at all).  I suggest you classify each of your issues and [log bug reports](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com) for them.

Comment: Have you tried this using Popup?